# Understanding monix consumer load balance

Tags: scala, reactive, monix

I am learning `monix 3`.

The next code:

```
object Main extends TaskApp {
  override def runc = {
    Observable.fromIterable(1 to 10)
      .map{i =>
        val delay = Random.nextInt(1000) + 1000
        println(s"Starting $i, delay = $delay")
        Thread.sleep(delay)     // Imitation of hard execution
        i
      }
      .map{i =>
        val delay = Random.nextInt(1000) + 1000
        println(s"Continue $i, delay = $delay")
        Thread.sleep(delay)
        i
      }
      .consumeWith(Consumer.loadBalance(3, Consumer.foreach(i => println(s"End $i"))))   //Compile error here
  }
}
```

leads to the compile error:

> missing parameter type
>         
> .consumeWith(Consumer.loadBalance(3, Consumer.foreach(i => println(s"End $i"))))

I can't figure out, what's wrong here, and how to make this code compile?

**UPD**
The second question is how to repeat this stream every `n` minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answer to your first question, you have to explicitly give a type parameter to `foreach`:

```
Consumer.foreach[Int](i => println(s"End $i"))
```

To answer your second question, use `Observable.intervalAtFixedRate` or `Observable.intervalAtFixedDelay`.

Please refer to the [Monix Scaladoc](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/reactive/index.html).

I hope this helps.